# Dynamically added link button click event does not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have dynamically added few link buttons inside a grid view with this code:

```
protected void gvTicketStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string compositeFiles = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

            // split the string into individual files using delemeter "?"
            string[] fileSet = compositeFiles.Split('?');

            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "";

            foreach (string str in fileSet)
            {
                if (str != null)
                {
                    // add a link button to the cell of the data grid.                                             

                    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                    lb.Text = "Download File";
                    lb.ID = str; // str is file URL
                    lb.Click += new EventHandler(lbStatus_click);

                    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lb);

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

In my event handler, I have read the URL from the ID and downloading the file as octet stream.

```
private void lbStatus_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = ((Control)sender).ID;
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);

        if (fileName != string.Empty && file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
            Response.AddHeader("content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        } 

    }
```

The link bottons appear in the webpage fine, but the problem is when I click on them, the page simply gets refreshed and nothing happens. The event handler code never gets executed.

Is this problem related to postback of the page? if yes then how can I solve it?

Comment: Might be some exception its catching during runtime. have you used try,catch ?If you have check for exceptions in your code. Also you can change access specifier to protected, private also works, but its better to do it protected, in case you need this event for another button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to suscribe to the command event of the grid view and add whatever information you need to the CommandArgs property.

*EDIT: Added example*

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e ){
    gvTicketStatus.RowCommand += new EventHandler(RowCommand);
}

protected void gvTicketStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string compositeFiles = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

            // split the string into individual files using delemeter "?"
            string[] fileSet = compositeFiles.Split('?');

            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "";

            foreach (string str in fileSet)
            {
                if (str != null)
                {
                    // add a link button to the cell of the data grid.                                             

                    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                    lb.Text = "Download File";
                    lb.CommandName = "download"; //this is useful if you need to add more links with different commands.
                    lb.CommandArgument = str;// str is file URL
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lb);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

In my event handler, I have read the URL from the ID and downloading the file as octet stream.

```
private void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        string fileName = e.CommandArgument;
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);

        if (fileName != string.Empty && file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
            Response.AddHeader("content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        } 

    }
```

For more information, please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hi ivowiblo, could you please elaborate it in a abit detail? thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior many times before when adding controls dynamically. Make sure that the code which binds your datagrid (which in turn executes your gvTicketStatus_RowDataBound event) runs after each and every page postback. This needs to occur in order for the linkbutton control to persist its click event after the postback.